# Shellcode that is smaller than 295 bytes that spawns a shell

Tags: metasploit, shellcode

Metasploit payloads produce more than 300-byte shellcodes.

But I want my shell-spawning shellcodes to be less than 295 bytes.

Can anyone show me the links to these shellcodes?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dark, welcome to [security.se]. Please see the [FAQ], and read [ask] - this question is very low quality, and does not show enough of your effort nor is it something specifically solvable.

Answer (score 2):

A null free 211 byte bind shellcode is available from  Dafydd Stuttard, NGS Software.

http://code.google.com/p/w32-bind-ngs-shellcode/

I tested it in my labs, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.exploit-db.com/shellcode/